# StackNavigator color changes when in 'back mode'

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a StackNavigator with a red background color. When I click a button to go to another page, the navigation bar's background color changes from red to the default white with the back button color blue. Is this expected behavior? if so, is there a clean workaround?

here's my code:

```js
class PageComponent extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'page1',
    headerBackTitle: null,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#ff005c',
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
      color: 'white' ,
    },
  };

  page2 = () => {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    navigate('page2');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          Feed page
        </Text>
        <Button onPress={this.page2} title='Go to page2' />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const FeedPage = StackNavigator({
  Page: {
    screen: PageComponent
  },
  page2: {
    screen: Page2,
  }
});
```

Page2

```js
const Page2 = TabNavigator({
  pagex: {
    screen: Pagex
  },
  pagey: {
    screen: Pagey
  },
  pagez: {
    screen: Pagez
  }
}, {
  tabBarPosition: 'top',
  animationEnabled: true,
  swipeEnabled: true,
});

export default BitePage;
```

Comment: have you defined the same `navigationOptions` in `Page2`?

Comment: @Val no I havent, that page uses a TabNavigator, and I dont want those styles to interfere

Comment: @Val Let me update the question with the page2 code and maybe you can show me the right way to do this

Comment: @Val ok updated the question

Comment: try my answer that gives `StackNavigator` default style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to make default header style.

This applies to child `TabNavigator`'s header too.

*Document of [Default Navigation Options](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-options#Default-Navigation-Options)*

```js
const FeedPage = StackNavigator({
  Page: {
    screen: PageComponent
  },
  page2: {
    screen: Page2,
  }
}, {
    navigationOptions: {
        headerBackTitle: null,
        headerStyle: {
           backgroundColor: '#ff005c',
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
           color: 'white' ,
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: ohhh, I see, that worked. I didn't realize it worked that way. Is there docs that explain this?

Comment: yes, see [Default Navigation Options](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-options#Default-Navigation-Options)